# In Django create a dummyuser (on startup?)

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

My goal is to have one dummyuser in the database. I already wrote the following function

```
def get_test_user():
    user, created = get_user_model.objects.get_or_create(username=TESTUSER_USERNAME)
    user.set_password(TESTUSER_PASSWORD)
    user.save
```

But where and how should I call it to achieve my goal. I am aware that testing django will create its own database and that there are functions for creating test users. But this should actually run in the production database as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.db import migrations


def create_user(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_registered_model('auth', 'User')
    user = User(
        username='user',
        email='user@mail.com',
        password=make_password('pass'),
        is_superuser=False,
        is_staff=False
    )
    user.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0001_initial')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_user),
    ]
```

Comment: This will cause your test database to not be empty by default. Every test you'll have a default user in the database. Don't use this approach if it's not requirement for your project. Just use sh or python scripts that are ran before application.